# Flatten List Before Appending to List

Tags: python

I have a function that pulls ports and appends them to a list.

```
def port_lookup(cmd=raidcom, a=awk):
    chk_port = subprocess.Popen('{cmd} get port | {a}'.
                                format(cmd=cmd, a=a), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, err) = chk_port.communicate()
    spl_port = out.split()
    port_chk = ", ".join([k.decode("utf8") for k in spl_port])
    avail_port.append(port_chk)
    return
```

Without the `join()` method I will get the following nested list due to the decode("utf8"):

```
avail_port = [['CL1-A', 'CL1-B', 'CL1-C', 'CL1-D', 'CL2-A',
               'CL2-B', 'CL2-C', 'CL2-D', 'CL3-A', 'CL3-B',
               'CL3-C', 'CL3-D', 'CL4-A', 'CL4-B', 'CL4-C', 
               'CL4-D']]
```

With the `join()` method it turns the list into one string.

```
avail_port = ['CL1-A, CL1-B, CL1-C, CL1-D, CL2-A,
               CL2-B, CL2-C, CL2-D, CL3-A, CL3-B, 
               CL3-C, CL3-D, CL4-A, CL4-B, CL4-C, 
               CL4-D']
```

How can I append my list so it is not nested and split into individual strings?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [list.extend](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html)(*Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list*) method instead of `append`(*Add an item to the end of the list;*) before joining the list as a string:

```
avail_port.extend([k.decode("utf8") for k in spl_port])
```